# Spring REST service response encoding issue

Tags: json, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

I have written one sample REST endpoint in Spring application.

The response of the endpoint is a List.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<String> getTest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("one = 1");
        list.add("two = 2");
        list.add("three = 3");
        list.add("four = 4");

        log.debug("List Size : " + list.size());

        return list;
    }
```

When i test this endpoint from postman tool the response was as expected

```
[
    "one = 1",
    "two = 2",
    "three = 3",
    "four = 4"
]
```

But when i invoke the same endpoint from java code using RestTemplate the response was different

```
["one \u003d 1","two \u003d 2","three \u003d 3","four \u003d 4"]
```

How to decode the response when invoking from a client program?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share java code for call this endpoint using resttemplate.

Answer (score 0):

I was taking the response into a string. That is why the decoding is not happening. If i take the response into some bean, i see the real values. So the issue is resolved by creating one bean to hold the json response.